# multiplying column of the file by exponential function

Tags: python, function, exponential

I,m struggling with multiplying one column file by an exponential function
so my equation is
**y=10.43^(-x/3.0678)+0.654**
The first values in the column are my **X** in the equation, so far I was  able to multiply only by scalars but with exponential functions not

the file looks like this

```
8.09
5.7
5.1713
4.74
4.41
4.14
3.29
3.16
2.85
2.52
2.25
2.027
1.7
1.509
0.76
0.3
0.1
```

So after the calculations, my Y should get these values

`````
8.7     0.655294908
8.09    0.656064021
5.7     0.6668238549
5.1713  0.6732091509
4.74    0.6807096436
4.41    0.6883719253
4.14    0.6962497391
3.29    0.734902438
3.16    0.7433536016
2.85    0.7672424605
2.52    0.7997286905
2.25    0.8331287249
2.027   0.8664148415
1.7    0.926724933
1.509   0.9695896976
0.76    1.213417197
0.3    1.449100509
0.1    1.580418766````
`````

So far this code is working for me  but it´s far away from what i want

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar 
import math 
col_list = ["Position"]
df = pd.read_csv("force.dat", usecols=col_list)
print(df)
A = df["Position"] 
X = ((-A/3.0678+0.0.654)
print(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you just want to apply a function to a column in a pandas dataframe, right? If so, you can define the function:

```
def foo(x):
    y = 10.43 ** (-x/3.0678)+0.654
    return y
```

and apply it to df in a new column. If `A` is the column with the `x` values, then `y` will be

```
df['y'] = df.apply(foo,axis=1)
```

Now `print(df)` should give you the example result in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line:

```py
>>> df['y'] = 10.43 ** (- df['x']/3.0678)+0.654
>>> print(df)

         x         y
0   8.0900  0.656064
1   5.7000  0.666824
2   5.1713  0.673209
3   4.7400  0.680710
4   4.4100  0.688372
5   4.1400  0.696250
6   3.2900  0.734902
7   3.1600  0.743354
8   2.8500  0.767242
9   2.5200  0.799729
10  2.2500  0.833129
11  2.0270  0.866415
12  1.7000  0.926725
13  1.5090  0.969590
14  0.7600  1.213417
15  0.3000  1.449101
16  0.1000  1.580419
```